# Using service aliases for dependency injection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

In my application I have an SMS service. This service is a simple POPO that takes an instance to a driver to do the actual SMS functionality.

Imagine I have two drivers, `mock_driver` and `gateway_driver` which are defined as something like this in the `services` section:

```
mock_driver:
    class: MyApp\Service\Sms\MockDriver

gateway_driver:
    class: MyApp\Service\Sms\GatewayDriver
    calls:
        - [setConfig, ["%gateway_user%", "%gateway_password%", "%gateway_endpoint%"]]
```

And the SMS service is defined like this:

```
service_sms:
    class: MyApp\Service\SmsService
    calls:
        - [setDriver, ["%service_sms_driver%"]]
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want to pass an "instance" of one of the two drivers into the `setDriver` method of my service. Which driver this is should be defined in my `parameters.yml`, something such as:

```
service_sms_driver: ["@mock_driver"]
```

However, I'm stuck on the syntax to make this work correctly. I think the gist of it is correct except for the syntax on the `service_sms_driver` value in my `parameters.yml` and the `setDriver` method call on the actual service.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**
Just as a clarification, both drivers implement the same interface. However, every driver might need different ways of configuration which might not be captured in an interface. If I was simply passing class names it would work fine but I'm trying to inject instances instead. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your services construct differently, the idea of [aliasing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#aliasing) seems to be a correct idea.
To do so, just create your two driver services and your manager. (*Note the usage of `@driver`*)

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
gateway_driver:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\GatewayDriver
mock_driver:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\MockDriver

manager:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\SmsManager
    arguments: [ @driver ]
```

Then, you can edit this alias into your `AcmeFooExtension` file

<kbd>**Acme/FooBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeFooExtension.php**</kbd>

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $driver = $container->getParameter('service_sms_driver');
    $container->setAlias('driver', $driver);
}
```

This will take the `service_sms_driver` parameter and create an alias of this service.

---

Example of debugging:

<kbd>**config_dev.yml**</kbd>

```
parameters:
    service_sms_driver: mock_driver
```

Running

```
$ php app/console --env=dev container:debug driver
```

Results in

> [container] Information for service driver
>   This service is an alias for the service mock_driver

---

<kbd>**config_prod.yml**</kbd>

```
parameters:
    service_sms_driver: gateway_driver
```

Running

```
$ php app/console --env=prod container:debug driver
```

Results in

> [container] Information for service driver
>   This service is an alias for the service gateway_driver

---

<kbd>**config_test.yml**</kbd>

```
parameters:
    service_sms_driver: unknown_driver
```

Running

```
$ php app/console --env=test container:debug driver
```

Results in

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The service definition "unknown_driver" does not exist.