# Injecting parameter based service into other service

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I have a service which takes a driver to do the actual work. The driver itself is within the context of Symfony 2 is just another service.

To illustrate a simplified version:

```
services:
  # The driver services.
  my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp:
    class: \My\Scope\Service\Driver\SmtpDriver

  my_scope.mailer_driver_mock:
    class: \My\Scope\Service\Driver\MockDriver

  # The actual service.
  my_scope.mailer:
    class: \My\Scope\Service\Mailer
    calls:
      - [setDriver, [@my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp]]
```

As the above illustrates, I can inject any of the two driver services into the Mailer service. The problem is of course that the driver service being injected is hard coded. So, I want to parameterize the `@my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp`.

I do this by adding an entry to my `parameters.yml`

```
my_scope_mailer_driver: my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp
```

I can then use this in my `config.yml` and assign the parameter to the semantic exposed configuration [1]:

```
my_scope:
  mailer:
    driver: %my_scope_mailer_driver%
```

In the end, in the `Configuration` class of my bundle I set a parameter onto the container:

```
$container->setParameter('my_scope.mailer.driver', $config['mailer']['driver'] );
```

The value for the container parameter `my_scope.mailer.driver` now equals the `my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp` that I set in the `parameters.yml`, which is, as my understanding of it is correct, just a string.

If I now use the parameter name from the container I get an error complaining that there is no such service. E.g:

```
services:
  my_scope.mailer:
    class: \My\Scope\Service\Mailer
    calls:
      - [setDriver, [@my_scope.mailer.driver]]
```

The above will result in an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                          
The service "my_scope.mailer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "my_scope.mailer.driver"
```

The question now is, what is the correct syntax to inject this container parameter based service?

[1] http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

Comment: You need to use [`$container->setAlias`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19356276/1607098) instead

Comment: Interesting. You point to the accepted answer of a question I asked previously. Do you think you can add that link above in an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This question has a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356276/1607098)

I think the best way to use this kind of definition is to use [service aliasing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#aliasing).
This may look like this

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeFooExtension**</kbd>

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration;
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    $alias = $config['mailer']['driver'];
    $container->setAlias('my_scope.mailer_driver', $alias);
}
```

This will alias the service you've defined in `my_scope.mailer.driver` with `my_scope.mailer_driver`, which you can use as any other service

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    my_scope.mailer_driver:
        alias: my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp # Fallback

    my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp:
        class: My\Scope\Driver\Smtp

    my_scope.mailer_driver_mock:
        class: My\Scope\Driver\Mock

    my_scope.mailer:
        class: My\Scope\Mailer
        arguments:
            - @my_scope.mailer_driver
```

With such a design, the service will change whenever you change the `my_scope.mailer_driver` parameter in your *config.yml*.
Note that the extension will throw an exception if the service doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

With [service container expression language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) you have access to the following two functions in config files:

- service - returns a given service (see the example below);
- parameter - returns a specific parameter value (syntax is just like service)

So to convert parameter name into a service reference you need something like this:

```
parameters:
  my_scope_mailer_driver: my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp

services:
  my_scope.mailer:
    class: \My\Scope\Service\Mailer
    calls:
      - [setDriver, [@=service(parameter('my_scope_mailer_driver'))]]
```

Comment: I just noticed this. This is a really nice way of doing this. Will try next time I have to do something like this.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought this was just a question of getting the @ symbol passed in properly.  But I tried assorted combinations and came to the conclusion that you can't pass an actual service as a parameter.  Maybe someone else will chime in and show how to do this.

So then I figured is was just a question of using the service definition and passing it a reference.  At first I tried this in the usual extension but the container does not yet contain all the service definitions.

So I used a compiler pass: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

The Pass class looks like:

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\AppCeradBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class Pass1 implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Set in the Extension: my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp
        $mailerDriverId = $container->getParameter('my_scope.mailer.driver');

        $def = $container->getDefinition('my_scope.mailer');

        $def->addMethodCall('setDriver', array(new Reference($mailerDriverId)));
    }
}
```

Take the calls section out of the service file and it should work.  I suspect there is an easier way but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

`@my_scope.mailer.driver` needs to be a service but not defined as service. To retrieve string parameter named as `my_scope.mailer.driver` you need to wrap it with `%`: `%my_scope.mailer.driver%`.

So you need to pass `@%my_scope.mailer.driver%` as parameter to a service. Yml parser will replace `%my_scope.mailer.driver%` with the appropriate value of the parameter and only then it will be called as a service.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried this but it doesn't work. I get a very similar error: ` The service "my_scope.mailer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "%my_scope.mailer.driver%"` (notice the percent symbols)

Comment: Remove the quotes around % signs

Comment: There's no quotes around it, the quotes are from the exception message. I'm using this: `[setDriver, [@%my_scope.mailer.driver%]]` which gives the error shown in my comment.

Comment: `@%my_scope.mailer.driver%` syntax does not work currently. Also `alias: %my_scope.mailer.driver%` does not work too. (Checked on Symfony 2.4.2).