# How to achieve something like having an expression in a parameter to inject into a service?

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, expression, parameter-passing

In a service definition, I inject a value via expression language:

```
someService:
    arguments:
        - "@=service('otherService').getValue()"
```

Now, some another service needs the same value, so I thought I could:

```
parameter:
    leValue: "@=service('otherService').getValue()"

someService:
    arguments:
        - "%leValue%"

yetAnotherService:
    arguments:
        - "%leValue"
```

Yet this earns me an exception:

> You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to
>   other services

Bummer. Is there another way to store an expression? I rather not repeat th full expression everytime I need it, and I am not fixed on using a parameter. My goal is to achieve a bit of syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

This question has a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352417/using-service-aliases-for-dependency-injection/19356276#19356276)

You have to use aliasing

Exemple :

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration;
    config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader(
    $container,
    new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
);
$loader->load('services.yml');

$alias = $config['mailer']['driver'];
$container->setAlias('my_scope.mailer_driver', $alias);
```

}

And in your Service.yml :

```
services:
my_scope.mailer_driver:
    alias: my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp # Fallback

my_scope.mailer_driver_smtp:
    class: My\Scope\Driver\Smtp

my_scope.mailer_driver_mock:
    class: My\Scope\Driver\Mock

my_scope.mailer:
    class: My\Scope\Mailer
    arguments:
        - @my_scope.mailer_driver
```